# Why put JSP in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsp

I noticed a common pattern is to put JSP pages in WEB-INF folder (as opposed to WAR root). What's the difference? Why is that preferred?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Files in `WEB-INF` are not visible to the users. It's a bit safer that way.

If (a contrived example) you are including `db.jsp`, but by itself it throws an exception, a malicious user can open `http://yoursite.com/db.jsp` and get some insight on your application (worst - the database credentials) from the exception message.

Comment: I don't get it... Won't you get just an HTML response when you open the URL of JSP instead of the JSP code? I may be missing something

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's a good design pattern, but I believe I can explain the reasoning.

Servlet containers won't serve any content in `WEB-INF`. By putting your JSPs there, you prevent anyone from directly accessing a JSP by navigating to it in the browser by name. This might be considered good practice, if some of your JSPs are just fragments of code/markup, and not meant to be used directly, and perhaps open some security hole you haven't though of.

It's still possible to get the container to see and use the JSPs as expected even in `WEB-INF`.

Comment: If it's not a good design pattern, what are the alternative solutions to the problems you explained?

Comment: I disagree. I think it is a very good pattern as it solves a real issue in a simple, robust and easily understandable way.

Comment: I agree with @pap. As 1) it enforces you to place a controller in front of the JSPs (Servlet, Action, etc.) and 2) it does hide Java specifics (.jsp ending).

Comment: That's not a **design** pattern at all.

Comment: Placing JSP files under WEB-INFis a good and officially recommened design pattern as it enforces an MVC approach. You can still use "public" JSP files in very simple applications.

Comment: As @BalusC pointed out it's not a *design* pattern. Certainly not in the sense meant by Christopher Alexander and not even in the Gang of Four sense. 
It doesn't say this solution is wrong, but please lookup what those "design patterns" are

Answer (score 5):

An extra-plus when using a `Controller` (or Front-Servlet) is that you decouple the URL path from the physical location of the JSP-files in your project.

As example here a simple request-mapping from a [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) `Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/item/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getItemEdit(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) final String id) {
    return "itemeditform";
}
```

The [ViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) takes care of mapping the URL to the place where your JSPs reside.