# Preventing a HTTP invalid direct reference to form login page prevent redirect

Tags: java, tomcat6

I'm using Java, and Tomcat6 (Uni requirements)

I know what causes this error, but I'm looking for a way to fix it. If someone types in http:\mywebsite.com\login.jsp it will throw an error on log in (and they won't be logged in).

Is there a way to force a redirect if the page isn't being accessed by the security section. Is there a way of overriding the existing login system (using an action?) and having a redirect from there, (or have it send me back to login page, and I can redirect if authenticated from there).

Answer (score 0):

Put JSPs (and any other resources) which should not be directly accessed – that is, ones which must be forwarded to from a servlet – under `WEB-INF`. [Why put JSP in WEB-INF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825907/why-put-jsp-in-web-inf)