# How to call image path using JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have my images forlder under web folder. With the complete path as "web/images/logo1.jpg". My jsp page was located web/WEB-INF/jsp. How can I correcly view my images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

Answer (score 1):

While specifying path of images we have two options: Providing Absolute path or relative path. Assuming you have a webapp ROOT i.e. all your code is inside webapps/ROOT ( ROOT is the default webapp in TOMCAT i.e. file inside webapps/ROOT/first.html can be accessed on browser using http://example.com:8080/first.html. )

Or if you have a webapp example; then webapps/example/first.html  can be accessed using http://example.com:8080/example/first.html

So, assuming you have following files webapps/ROOT/jsp/first.jsp ; and webapps/ROOT/images/logo1.jpg

Inside logo1.jsp you can access the jpg as follows:

```
<img src="/images/logo1.jpg" /> (absolute path; because it starts with a slash ; this slash is mapped to the starting directory)
<img src="../images/logo1.jpg" /> (relative path; because it DOES NOT starts with a slash ; you have to give path relative to location of your jsp )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have pass the relative url of the project which you can pass using getContextRoot() as shown:

/images/logo1.jpg"/>

Answer (score -4):

Why is your jsp located in the WEB-INF directory? Kinda odd?
I'm usually using something like /web/jsp for my jsp files. WEB-INF should be dedicated to web.xml and suchies.. at least I think so :)

Anyways, anything in the web root may be accessed as
/foldername/file.ext

In your case, you should be able to use

```
<img src="/images/logo1.jpg" />
```

Comment: JSP's in WEB-INF is a good practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825907/why-put-jsp-in-web-inf