# Slide menu with JSP in WEB-INF directory

Tags: jsp, menu

I need to Implement Slide menu in my application but I have my jsp in WEB-INF/pages Directory. Of course I cannot Access these pages from href. How should I go about this?

My slide menu example:

```
<li class="SlideMenu1_Folder"><div><a href="#">SCHOOL FEES</a></div><span><!-- empty --></span>
                        <ul style="display:none">
                            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/pages/coursefeessetup.jsp">Set Course Fees</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/pages/configurebankaccount.jsp">Configure Bank Account</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/pages/payschoolfees.jsp">Pay Fees</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/pages/studentfeesinquiry.jsp">Fee Inquiry</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/WEB-INF/pages/studentFeeStatement.jsp">Fee Statement</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

This is returning that the page is not found. What is the best way to implement this type of menu while retaining the JSPs inside the WEB-INF directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here was to invoke a servlet like this:

```
<li><a href="myservlet">Set Course Fees</a></li>
```

and then inside my servlet:

```
String path = request.getServletPath();
if(path.equal("/myservlet")){
request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/myjsppage.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in WEB-INF are not publicly visible. This is for security. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825956/1389219

You must either pull them out of the WEB-INF folder, or (recommended) use an MVC framework such as Spring MVC and map URLs like `/course-fees-setup` to `/WEB-INF/pages/coursefeessetup.jsp`.