# Redirct to TMLpage without using controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

nowadays i am learning how to work with spring framework , i am trying to build a simple web application, i have encountered a problem which i want you to help to solve.

in short, i want to redirect to HTML or JSP page without using a controller i know that i can do this using JSTL core library (c:url) in my case. every thing work properly until i click on the link (back to search) an 404 error pop up says this resource is not available.
** This is the only part that is not working properly with me **

First of all

Here is the App folder hierarchy:

**Web Application Hierarchy Image**

[image: Web Application Hierarchy Image]

Here is my JSP page which from i want to go back to search page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:url var="url"  value="/jsp/test.html"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>${id}</p>
<h1>Book Added Success</h1>

  <a href= "${url}">Back To Search</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Help Please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **No** due to you have put all your jsp files under `WEB-INF`

You can not access files within `WEB-INF`,more details can be found at [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-ee-web-application)

If you want to redirect without via Controller method,you need change the location of it,make them out of `WEB-INF`

Comment: Thank you about your answer , i have done as you told but i am still getting the same result.

Comment: is it good practice to add a request handler method to every JSPi have in my project ??

Comment: @Abed see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825907/why-put-jsp-in-web-inf